# `dependencies` of npm-library was not appear in `node-modules` of dependency

Tags: node.js, npm

My library requires `ts-loader` for operating, no just for development build:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-library",
  // ...
  "dependencies": {
    // ...
    "ts-loader": "6.0.4",
    // ...
  }
}
```

I expect that when I install "my-library" in other project as dependency, in `node_modules/my-library/node_modules`, `ts-loader` will appear. However, there are no most of `dependencies` of `my-library` in `node_modules/my-library/node_modules`:

[image]

It looks like my hypothesis "If set libraries in 'depencencies' filed of 'package.json' of 'some_dependency', those will be installed to `node_modules/some_dependency/node_module`, when `some_dependency` becomes to npm-library and will be installed" is wrong. Where it is wrong?

Comment: The dependencies of `my-library` will appear in `node_modules`, not in `node_modules/my-library/node_modules`. That way, common dependencies will not be copied more than once.

Comment: Got it! And solve my problem... Thank you for the answer!